# Is there a way to force svcutil.exe to ignore SSL certificate issues?

Tags: ssl, https, service, svcutil.exe

I need svcutil.exe to generate a proxy class for me, but the problem is that the web service can be accessed only via HTTPS and the SSL certificate is self signed.

How can I force svcutil.exe to ignore this issue?

Comment: This not directly the situation described in the question but the SSL certificate hostname mismatch (i.e. in a cluster scenario or a DNS suffix, etc.) can be worked around via svcutil.exe.config, you just need to add this:   <system.net>
    <settings>
      <servicePointManager checkCertificateName="false"/>
    </settings>
  </system.net>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try browsing to the https site first, ignore the warning that the certificate is not trusted, then click on the certificate and install it.

This should result in the machine you are working on trusting the certificate.

Then try running svcutil again.

Comment: I was thinking more of a "ignore the issue" switch, but I actually used your solution in the end.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

One thing that seemed to work was to fire up Fiddler and have it running as you make the SVCUTIL requests.  Fiddler's cert is valid and seems to work fine.

Comment: This certainly helped me. At least it did with the addition of the suggestion by @MattPll about ensuring the Decrypt HTTPS option is selected (at least, that is what worked for me).

Answer (score 6):

+1 for using fiddler.  You just need to go to the TOOLS > Fiddler Options and check Decrypt HTTPS.

Comment: I think the suggestion of Decrypt HTTPS is important for this to work. It certainly helped me out.

Comment: worked for me. wish our sysadmin's understood the beauty of a property implemented public key infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Browse to the https site, ignore the warning, save the wsdl, and generate the client class directly from the wsdl

Comment: I actually needed to run svcutil from another process. Shiraz Bhaiji's workaround worked well. I just made sure the certificate is installed, then svcutil run fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use curl with the --insecure flag to download the wsdl locally, then generate the classes from that.

```
curl --insecure "https://url_to_the_wsdl" >download.wsdl
svcutil.exe download.wsdl
```

Feel free to modify file names as appropriate, adding switches as required.